# Does Load Data Infile load all data to memory first?

Tags: mysql

I have a data file with 10 millions rows, with 2 fields, id and name. The total size of the file is 650 MB.

How long does it take to load this data to the database table? It's an intersection table for a many to many relationship.

It seems to be taking a long time to do this. While it's loading, I try executing a select statement. However, it's empty.

```
MariaDB [wordDS]> select count(*) from Category_Term;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (12.02 sec)
```

The Load Data Infile has been running for quite a while, and why isn't any data loaded into the table yet?  I suspect all data rows will be read into memory first, and then eventually written into table at the end of the loading. Otherwise, I can use a 'select *' statement to check the loading status.

Answer (score 0):

On tables that support it, like InnoDB, this is usually loaded inside the context of a transaction so you won't see anything until it completes. Then all the data is suddenly available.

If you need to load it in piece by piece you may need to convert your one spreadsheet into multiple parts and load those in sequentially.

I like breaking huge files up into smaller parts so you get a sense of progress. It's a lot better to see "file 23/100 complete" than "file 0/1 complete".

Comment: Do you have an estimate of how long it will take to load the 10 millions rows?

Comment: Depends entirely on your MySQL database tuning, the hardware, the server load, other queries on the table... Have a look at `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as a rough idea as to what's up. It could be anywhere from thirty seconds to never if you're experiencing some super bad luck.

Comment: A whole night and day, and still not finished. Is this normal?

Comment: Have a look at your process list and CPU load. Is it even doing anything? It might be stuck.

Comment: Sounds jammed to me. Maybe you've got a deadlock condition. Worth asking on the [DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) for how to diagnose this. If you're just doing a `LOAD DATA INFILE` you're doing it the right way in theory.